# How to pass the custom error message for data annotation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If i have a data contracts in separate project and i will use the data contract in the website. And now i want to give the custom error message for the data member.

How can i achieve this in the C#, ASP.Net

for example:

```
[DataMember]
[Required]
public string City { get; set; }
```

How can i give the customized message - ErrorMessage = "City is required." for the data contract?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it in the validationAttribute:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="your custom message here")]
    public object MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product 
{
     [NotMapped] // <--
     public const string priceStartsAt = "price starts at $5.00"; // <--
                
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [Range(5, 10000, ErrorMessage = priceStartsAt)] // <--
     public string FullDescription { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
     [Range(5, 10000, ErrorMessage = priceStartsAt)] // <--
     public decimal VendorPrice { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
     [Range(5, 10000, ErrorMessage = priceStartsAt)] // <--
     public decimal CustomerPrice { get; set; }  
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
     [Range(5, 10000, ErrorMessage = priceStartsAt)] // <--
     public decimal OldCustomerPrice { get; set; }
}
```